# When does an element become available in dom after using vue v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When does an element become available in the dom after using a vue `v-if`?  I would have thought you could do a query selector on the element after the `v-if` evaluates to true?

In the below code I need to get the `.test` element once the popout is shown but it shows as null - how do I get it?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      showPopout: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    buttonClick(day) {
      this.showPopout = true;
      console.log(document.querySelector('.test'));
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <span @click="buttonClick">show popout</span>
  <div v-if="showPopout"><span class="test">test</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps after *nextTick*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be there after `nextTick`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      showPopout: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    buttonClick(day) {
      this.showPopout = true;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(document.querySelector('.test'));
      });
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <span @click="buttonClick">show popout</span>
  <div v-if="showPopout"><span class="test">test</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks, will accept when it lets me :)

Comment: @Pete - I've only tested with Firefox by the way - I know Chrome can be weird with this sort of stuff!

Comment: Seems to work fine in chrome, ta